# One Chart- One Measure at a time being displayed

Tags: powerbi

Can I have multiple charts in Power BI or create different chart types and create a parameter so that I only display 1 chart at a time. Is that a possibility within Power BI?

For example: 
Year over Year
Month by Month
A measure of Month/Average as different measures.

Can I have a drop down as to which measures are selected and have the ability to be only select them one at the time?

Comment: Note that the October 2017 release of PowerBI permits hiding visuals. I haven’t tried it yet but that is related to your question too.

Comment: ahh perfect thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're asking a few questions there. I can answer one of them:

> Can I have a drop down as to which measures are selected and have the ability to be only select them one at the time?

You could create a table

```
My Measures = DATATABLE("My Measure", STRING, {{"Measure 1"}, {"Measure 2"}})
```

and on that table a measure

```
Selected Measure = SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('My Measures'[My Measure], BLANK()), "Measure 1", [Measure 1], "Measure 2", [Measure 2])
```

and then use the `[My Measure]` column as a slicer (which can be a drop-down menu). Then when you select "Measure 1" from the slicer, the `[Selected Measure]` measure will switch to showing the values of `[Measure 1]`.

This works best if all of the measures that you want to interchange have the same number formatting.